# How to change two models using a single foreign key?

Tags: django, database, django-models, database-design

So I have a model `Part` which contains `ConnectedTo`, which is a  `models.ForeignKey('self')`.

This is supposed to function in the same way the naming suggests. If a part is connected to another part, it is listed. My problem comes when dealing with the first object created, and linking objects to parts not yet created. If I have a `Part` `A`, then it is connected to nothing because no other objects exist yet. Even though I know it is connected to `B` which doesn't exist yet. I can create `B` and refer it to the other part when I create it, but this does nothing to change the `ConnectedTo` value in `A`.

I could easily write something to change both whenever something is added, but this system is designed to become quite large scale and I feel like I need a more automatic solution before it gets out of hand.

Comment: _Why_ you can't change `A.ConnectedTo` when you add `B`? Try using signals to automate that.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would even need signals. Why not just `B.objects.create(..., connectedTo=A)`?

Comment: @PedramParsian That might work... I think post save could help. I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: @DanielRoseman because that only changes it for B. 'A.ConnectedTo' is still null in that scenario

Comment: Well it feels like your relationships are wrong then. Why would both items have an FK to each other? Do you in fact want a many-to-many relationship? Or a one-to-one?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry that's probably the issue! I'm fairly inexperienced with database design. I think it would be many to many possibly? I'm not setting any limits on how many parts can be attached to which part. But the issue in question is that when I say Part A is connected to Part B then logically Part B is also connected to Part A.

Comment: Yes, a [symmetrical many-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) - which is the default - will do that. When you add A to B's connected_to, then B will automatically be a connected_to for A.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Perfect! Thank you. This worked for me! The only issue I'm having with this is that it now no longer shows as a column in my database table. Why is this?

Comment: Because a many-to-many relationship is a set of entries in a linking table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right your problem is that you can't create an instance if it's foreign key doesn't exist.

As a solution you can create the deepest Part first and when going up to create another. Like you have chain like `A -> B -> C`

```
c = Part.objects.create()
b = Part.objects.create(connected_to=c)
a = Part.objects.create(connected_to=b)
```

The other solution is to set `None` for parent instance until a new child instance is created. In case you need to create it before the child one. And with `post_save` or in save method you can do:

```
b = Part.objects.create()

c = Part.objects.create()
```

And on on `post_save` you can make:

```
parts = Part.objects.filter(id=b.id)
parts.update(connected_to=c) 
# I didn't use save method here in order to to call post_save again.
```